# While executing this fortran 95 code it gives me an error PARAB - in file hammer.f95 at line 221 [+0203] main - in file hammer.f95 at line 171 [+2e49]

Tags: matrix, fortran

While executing this fortran 95 code it gives me an error                      PARAB -  in file hammer.f95 at line 221 [+0203]  main -  in file hammer.f95 at line 171 [+2e49]
It shows that reference to an undefined variable, array element, or function result
It is showing this error for "y" vector
but I have already defined it by giving seven inputs in "y" vector

program hammer
    !Analysis of water hammer in the pipeline caused by opening or
    !closing of a downstream valve

```
!Pipeline may have up to 10 pipes in series, and each pipe may have 
!up to 100 computational nodes; this limits can be increased by 
!modifying the dimension statement

!Wave velocity is adjusted, if necessary, to avoid interpolation error

!Relative valve opening vs time curve is specified at discrete points and
!values at intermediate times are determined by parabolic interpolation

!SI units are used here.

!====================Notation====================!
!   a       = wave speed (m/s)
!   ar      = pipe c/s area (m2)
!   d       = pipe diameter (m)
!   dt      = computational time interval (s)
!   dxt     = time interval for storing tau vs time curve (s)
!   f       = darcy-weisbach friction factor
!   h       = piexometric head at beginning of time interval (m)
!   hmax    = maximum piezometric head (m)
!   hmin    = minimum piezometrci head (m)
!   hp      = piezometric head at end of the time interval (m)
!   hres    = reservoir level above datum (m)
!   hs      = valve head loss for flow of qs (m)
!   iprint  = number of time interval after which condition are to be printed
!   l       = pipe length (m)
!   m       = number of points on tau vs time curve
!   n       = number of reaches into which pipe is subdivided
!   np      = number of pipes 
!   nrlp    = number of reaches on last pipe
!   q       = discharge at beginning of time interval (m3/s)
!   qo      = steady state discharge (m3/s)
!   qp      = discharge at the end of time interval (m3/s)
!   qs      = valve discharge (m3/s)
!   t       = time (s)
!   tau     = relative valve opening
!   tauf    = final valve opening
!   tauo    = initial valve opening
!   tlast   = time upto which conditions are to be computed (s)
!   tv      = valve opening or closing time (s)
!   y       = stored tau values
!================================================!
implicit none
real , dimension(10,100) :: q,h,qp,hp,hmax,hmin
real , dimension(10)     :: ca,f,cf,ar,a,l,n,d,y,an,aunadj,ani
integer                  :: np,nrlp,iprint,m,i,j,k,nn,np1,jp1,jm1,nm1
real                     :: qo,hres,tlast,g,tv,dxt,tauo,tauf,qs,hs,dt,t,tau,cn,cp,cv
!reading and writing tha data

    g=9.81
    print *,'Enter np,nrlp,iprint,qo,hres,tlast'
    read *,np,nrlp,iprint,qo,hres,tlast 
    write (*,1) np,nrlp
    write (*,2) qo,hres
    write (*,3) tlast
    1 format (8x, 'Number of pipes=',i3/8x,'Number of reaches on last pipe=',i3)
    2 format (8x,'Steady state discharge=',f6.3,' m3/s'/8x,'Reservoir level=',f6.1,' m')
    3 format (8x,'Time for which transients computed=',f6.1,' s'/)

!data for valve

    print *,'Enter m,tv,dxt,tauo,tauf,qs,hs,y'
    read *,m,tv,dxt,tauo,tauf,qs,hs,(y(i),i=1,m)
    write (*,4) m,tv
    write (*,5) dxt,hs,qs
    write (*,6) (y(i),i=1,m)
    4 format (8x, 'Number of points on tau vs time curve=',i2/8x,'Valve operation time=',f6.2,' s')
    5 format (8x, 'Time interval for storing tau curve=',f6.3' s'/8x,'Valve loss=',f6.2,' m for qs=',f6.3,' m3/s')
    6 format (8x, 'Stored tau values:'/8x,15f8.3/)

!data for pipes

    print *,'Enter l,d,a,f'
    read *,(l(i),d(i),a(i),f(i),i=1,np)
    write (*,7)
    7 format (/8x, 'Pipe no',5x, 'Length',5x , 'Dia',5x, 'Wave vel.',5x, 'Fric factor'/21x,'(m)',7x,'(m)',7x, '(m/s)')
    write (*,8)(i,l(i),d(i),a(i),f(i),i=1,np)
    8 format (10x, i3,6x, f7.1,3x, f5.2,5x, f7.1,11x, f5.3)
    dt=l(np)/(nrlp*a(np))
    write (*,9)
    9 format(/8x,'Pipe no',5x,'Adjusted wave velocity'/27x,'(m/s)')

! calculation of pipe constants 
    do i=1,np
        ar(i)=0.7854*d(i)*d(i)
        aunadj(i)=a(i)
        an(i)=l(i)/(dt*a(i))
        n(i)=an(i)
        ani(i)=n(i)
            if (an(i)-ani(i) >= 0.5) n(i)=n(i)+1
        a(i)=l(i)/(dt*n(i))
        write(*,10) i,a(i)
        10 format (10x, i3,12x, f7.1)
        ca(i)=g*ar(i)/a(i)
        cf(i)=f(i)*dt/(2.0*d(i)*ar(i))
        f(i)=f(i)*l(i)/(2.0*g*d(i)*n(i)*ar(i)*ar(i))
    end do

!Calculation of steady state

    h(1,1)=hres
        do i=1,np
            nn=n(i)+1
                do j=1,nn
                    h(i,j)=h(i,1)-(j-1)*f(i)*qo*qo
                    q(i,j)=qo
                end do
            h(i+1,1)=h(i,nn)
        end do
    nn=n(np)+1
    if (qo /= 0.) hs=h(np,nn)
        do i=1,np
            nn=n(i)+1
                do j=1,nn
                    hmax(i,j)=h(i,j)
                    hmin(i,j)=h(i,j)
                end do
        end do
    np1=np-1
    t=0.0
    tau=tauo
    write(*,11)
    11 format (/8x,'Time',2x,'Tau',2x,'Pipe',7x,'Head (m)',7x,'Disch. ','(m3/s)'/20x,'No',5x,'(1)',5x,'(n+1)',5x,'(1)',5x,'(n+1)'/)             
    128 k=0
    i=1
    nn=n(i)+1
    write(*,12) t,tau,i,h(i,1),h(i,nn),q(i,1),q(i,nn)
    12 format (f12.1,f6.3,i4,2f9.2,f9.3,f10.3)
    if (np == 1) go to 14

        do i=2,np
            nn=n(i)+1
            write(*,13) i,h(i,1),h(1,nn),q(i,1),q(i,nn)
            13 format (20x,i2,2f9.2,f9.3,f10.3)
        end do
    14 t=t+dt
       k=k+1

    if ( t>tlast) go to 19

! Upstream reservoir

    hp(1,1)=hres
    cn=q(1,2)-h(1,2)*ca(1)*q(1,2)*abs(q(1,2))
    qp(1,1)= cn+ca(1)*hres

!interior points
        do i=1,np
            nn=n(i)
                do j=2,nn
                    jp1=j+1
                    jm1=j-1
                    cn=q(i,jp1)-ca(i)*h(i,jp1)-cf(i)*q(i,jp1)*abs(q(i,jp1))
                    cp=q(i,jm1)+ca(i)*h(i,jm1)-cf(i)*q(i,jm1)*abs(q(i,jm1))
                    qp(i,j)=0.5*(cp+cn)
                    hp(i,j)=(cp-qp(i,j))/ca(i)
                end do
        end do


!valve at downstream end

    nn=n(np)+1
    nm1=n(np)
    cn=q(np,nm1)+ca(np)*h(np,nm1)-cf(np)*q(np,nm1)*abs(q(np,nm1)) 
    if (t > tv) go to 15
    call parab(t,dxt,y,tau)
    go to 16
    15 tau=tauf  
    if (tau < 0.0) go to 17
    16 cv=(qs*tau)**2/(hs*ca(np))
       qp(np,nn)=0.5*(-cv+sqrt(cv*cv+4.*cp*cv))
       hp(np,nn)=(cp-qp(np,nn))/ca(np)
       go to 18
    17 qp(np,nn)=0.0
       hp(np,nn)=cp/ca(np)

! storing variables for next time step

    18 do i=1,np
            nn=n(i)+1
                do j=1,nn
                    q(i,j)=qp(i,j)
                    h(i,j)=hp(i,j)
                    if (h(i,j) > hmax(i,j)) hmax(i,j)=h(i,j)
                    if (h(i,j) < hmin(i,j)) hmin(i,j)=h(i,j)  
                end do
       end do

    if (k==iprint) go to 128
    go to  14
    19 write(*,20)
    20 format (/8x,'Pipe no.',3x,'Section no.',3x,'Max press.',3x,'Min press.'/)

    do i=1,np
        nn=n(i)+1
            do j=1,nn
            write(*,21) i,j,hmax(i,j),hmin(i,j)
            21 format (9x,i2,13x,i2,2f13.2)
            end do
    end do
    stop

end program hammer

subroutine parab(t,dxt,y,tau)
implicit none
real ,dimension(10) ::y
real                ::t,dxt,tau,r
integer             ::i
    i=t/dxt
    r=(t-i*dxt)/dxt

    if (i==0) r=r-1
      i=i+1
    if (i<2) i=2
      tau=y(i)+0.5*r*(y(i+1)-y(i-1)+r*(y(i+1)-y(i-1)-2.0*y(i)))  
end subroutine parab



_______output____of____the _____program__________________________________________
 Enter np,nrlp,iprint,qo,hres,tlast
1
2
2
1.0
67.7
10
        Number of pipes=  1
        Number of reaches on last pipe=  2
        Steady state discharge= 1.000 m3/s
        Reservoir level=  67.7 m
        Time for which transients computed=  10.0 s

 Enter m,tv,dxt,tauo,tauf,qs,hs,y
7
6.0
1.0
1.0
0.0
1.0
60.05
1.0
0.9
0.7
0.5
0.3
0.1
0.0
        Number of points on tau vs time curve= 7
        Valve operation time=  6.00 s
        Time interval for storing tau curve= 1.000 s
        Valve loss= 60.05 m for qs= 1.000 m3/s
        Stored tau values:
           1.000   0.900   0.700   0.500   0.300   0.100   0.000
 Enter l,d,a,f
550.0
0.75
1100
0.01

        Pipe no     Length     Dia     Wave vel.     Fric factor
                     (m)       (m)       (m/s)
            1        550.0    0.75      1100.0           0.010

        Pipe no     Adjusted wave velocity
                           (m/s)
            1             1100.0

        Time  Tau  Pipe       Head (m)       Disch. (m3/s)
                    No     (1)     (n+1)     (1)     (n+1)

         0.0 1.000   1    67.70    65.78    1.000     1.000
         0.5 0.712   1    67.70    99.31    1.004     0.875
         1.0 0.900   1    67.70    44.98    0.841     0.744
         1.5 0.563   1    67.70   119.01    0.913     0.757
         2.0 0.700   1    67.70    87.16    0.760     0.806
         2.5 0.375   1    67.70    87.52    0.853     0.433
         3.0 0.500   1    67.70   101.48    0.682     0.621
         3.5 0.225   1    67.70    81.32    0.726     0.250
         4.0 0.300   1    67.70   112.94    0.615     0.393
         4.5 0.075   1    67.70   111.87    0.601     0.098
         5.0 0.100   1    67.70   134.83    0.487     0.143
         5.5-0.038   1    67.70   147.87    0.430     0.056
```

Comment: Had you used the [tag:fortran] tag, someone might have actually seen and answered your question...

Comment: What's the actual error message?